# Visual Studio 2022 stuck in Build

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm currently using VS2022 Community Edition and has updated it to the latest version (17.6.3). I updated to this version because whenever I launch a console application after the first run, the build is just stuck at "Building". It would require me to restart my machine before this would actually work. I can't even stop the build if not forcing task manager to stop the process.

I tried the following:

- Deleting bin/obj folders
- Uncheck code analysis in the project properties
- Clean solution

I also tried opening the product in Rider but the result is the same. I am suspecting this might be a MSbuild issue but I don't know what causes this.

Console app:
C#, .net 4.8

Comment: Turn on Diagnostic-level MSBuild output logging under Tools > Options > Build and look at the build-logs in the Output window. Also, try using .NET 7+ instead of .NET Framework 4.8 as it has a different build system. Does it hang if you use .NET 7+ and build via running `dotnet build` from the command-line (instead of from within VS's Build button)?

Comment: The application is a legacy .net 4.8 app so I don't think I can build it with .net core.

Comment: Right - I meant creating a quick toy program to verify that you can build those at least.